# Box In new page

Tags: html, paypal

I am trying to get a PayPal link/button to open on another page instead of opening on the same page. It is an old site so I was looking for the best way to update it. The link is as follows. Thanks in advance!

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top"><input name="cmd" type="hidden" value="_s-xclick" />
<input name="hosted_button_id" type="hidden" value="XXXXX" />
<input alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" name="submit" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" type="image" />
<img src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" alt="" width="1" height="1" border="0" /></form>
```

Comment: Note that the `<input>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0):

With that old style button code, you can accomplish what you want by changing `target="_top"` to `target="paypal"` (or _blank)

---

However, the best solution would be to change to using a smart button, which uses an in-context approval flow rather than a separate browser tab. You can create one for your account via https://www.paypal.com/buttons , first option

(There's also a [code demo here](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client), and [full documentation here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/set-up-standard-payments/))

Answer (score 0):

Simply change your target to `target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"`. The target _blank opens a new tab for you without closing the original. noopener and noreferrer is a good security measure.